# Responsive e-mail - table cell into new line if short screen without media query

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive email html. I have 3 items I want to show in table. If screen is shorter, then the last item should go into new line. Something like [here](http://email-templates.org/emails/magicshop/templates/layout1/mixed.html). Is it possible to make anything like that without media queries?

This is my simplified code:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="170" valign="top" style="background-color:green;">item 1 eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</td>
    <td width="16"></td>
    <td width="170" valign="top" style="background-color:green;">item 2 eeeeeeeeeee</td>
    <td width="16"></td>
    <td class="content" width="186" valign="top" style="background-color:green;">item 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried to use display:inline on td which do the job, but then the spacing between product wont adjusted.

Comment: You know that only Apple Mail supports responive email CSS, right? https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: What do you mean by responsive email css? It seems "display" is supported.